# How to code recursive string other parameter in Ocaml

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I want to code like `string(2^n)`.

ex.

```
let string2 s = 
    match s with
    " " -> " "
    | _ -> s^s;;
```

but,

```
let rec string128 s = 
    match s with 
      " " -> " " 
    | _ -> string128 s^s ;;
```

it has overflow. how can I code only using recursive function? 
i don't want to use other parameter. like `n -> n-1'

if i put 'a' in the string128 then repeating 'a' 128 times.

Comment: It "overflows" because no concatenation of any string with itself will ever produce the base case of `" "`, so it will recurse infinitely. It's otherwise unclear what you're trying to do since "like `string(2^n)`" does not make any sense. If you can provide a few examples of input and expected output from your function it might be possible to decipher what you want to accomplish, but otherwise you'd have to actually try to explain it.

Comment: if i input "a" in string128  then repeating ' a ' 128 times . This is what i want to make.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Could you update your question to include that example?

Comment: I did. What should i change in  base case?

Comment: I may understand badly, but why don't you want to use another parameter? your string is constant, it has no other information your recursive function can use to know when to stop?

Comment: 2^n is stop condition. If 2^n is 4 and input "a"  then print "aaaa" .

Comment: What's `n`? There is no `n` in your code. Is it just the length of your input string? If so, your last example does not make sense. With `"a"` as input `2^n == 2`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand why you don't want to use an extra parameter, but you can use the length of the string as a terminating condition. Since it is not clear what you want to do with an initial string that has more than one character, here are two possible versions:

```
let rec string128 s = 
  if String.length s >= 128 then s 
  else string128 (s^s);;

let string128bis s =
  let orig_length = String.length s in
  let rec aux s =
    if String.length s >= 128 * orig_length then s 
    else aux (s^s)
  in 
  aux s;;
```

`string128` will concatenate the strings until the result is at least 128 characters wide. `string128bis` will wait for the resulting string to be 128 times longer than the original input. Both `string128 "a"` and `string128bis a` will return 128 `a`, but `string128 "abcd"` will return a 128-characters string repeating `abcd`, while `string128bis "abcd"` will be 512 characters long.